# Selenium 4.0 Kubernetes deployment failing at node registration

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-grid

In Kubernetes cluster I am trying to build a selenium hub and node. I am able to do it in the distributive mode, but trying to do in hub node mode.

## Hub-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-hub
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-hub
          image: selenium/hub:4.0 
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4444
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 1000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

## hub-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "selenium-hub"
    port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: ClusterIP
```

## node-chrome-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: selenium-chrome-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-chrome-node
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-chrome-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-chrome-node
          image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0
          env:
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
              value: "selenium-hub"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
              value: "4442"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
              value: "4443"
            - name: SE_NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS
              value: "8"
            - name: SE_SESSION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
              value: "3600"
            - name: SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS
              value: "10"
            - name: SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS    
              value: "true"      
            - name: SE_NODE_GRID_URL
              value: "http://selenium-hub:4444"
            - name: HUB_HOST
              value: "selenium-hub"
            - name: HUB_PORT
              value: "4444"  
            - name: SE_NODE_HOST
              value: "selenium-chrome-node"
            - name: SE_NODE_PORT
              value: "5555"  
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 1000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5555
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /dev/shm
              name: dshm
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
```

## node-chrome-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-chrome-node
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "selenium-chrome-node"
    port: 5555 
    targetPort: 5555
  selector:
    app: selenium-chrome-node
  type: ClusterIP
```

Logs:

```
[events]
publish = "tcp://selenium-hub:4442"
subscribe = "tcp://selenium-hub:4443"

[server]
host = "selenium-chrome-node"
port = "5555"
[node]
grid-url = "http://selenium-hub:4444"
session-timeout = "300"
override-max-sessions = true
detect-drivers = false
max-sessions = 10

[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "chrome"
stereotype = '{"browserName": "chrome", "browserVersion": "95.0", "platformName": "Linux"}'
max-sessions = 10
.
.
.
17:00:27.549 INFO [NodeServer$1.start] - Starting registration process for node id d6a68bf5-e5b4-483a-9e71-408b3c158c0b
17:00:27.609 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): http://selenium-chrome-node:5555
17:00:27.621 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
17:00:37.629 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
17:00:47.636 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
17:00:57.641 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
17:01:07.646 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
17:01:17.650 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
```

This registration never happens

Logs of hub pod:

```
4443, advertising as tcp://100.106.0.5:4443]
17:00:25.242 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://100.106.0.5:4442 and tcp://100.106.0.5:4443
17:00:25.324 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
17:00:26.333 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
17:00:27.621 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): http://100.106.0.5:4444
```

How to get the selenium hub 4.0 and chrome-node 4.0 registered ?

Answer (score 1):

The hub also needs to expose the publisher and subscriber ports, so that the it can be reached by your node/chrome pod. Update to the following:

**hub-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "selenium-hub"
    port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
  - name: "subscribe-events"
    port: 4443
    targetPort: 4443
  - name: "publish-events"
    port: 4442
    targetPort: 4442
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: ClusterIP
```

Also found that you have legacy env variables from grid v3 and the v4 alpha/beta releases for your node. These need to be removed, see amended config below:

**node-chrome-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: selenium-chrome-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-chrome-node
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-chrome-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-chrome-node
          image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0
          env:
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
              value: "selenium-hub"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
              value: "4442"
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
              value: "4443"
            - name: SE_SESSION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
              value: "3600"
            - name: SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS
              value: "10"
            - name: SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS
              value: "true"
            - name: SE_NODE_GRID_URL
              value: "http://selenium-hub:4444"
            - name: SE_NODE_HOST
              value: "selenium-chrome-node"
            - name: SE_NODE_PORT
              value: "5555"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 1000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5555
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /dev/shm
              name: dshm
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
```

Configuration that has been removed:

- SE_NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS
- HUB_HOST
- HUB_PORT

Comment: It is not working. Found the below in logs of hub pod.  ''' 05:36:31.983 INFO [Node.<init>] -Binding additional locator mechanisms: id, relative, name '''

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @sunil - I have notice some issues with the node/chrome configuration as well. It had a mix of legacy (v3), alpha/beta and v4 config. I have stripped what is not required and updated answer above. Please try again.

Comment: Nice findings mate, it really really helped me a lot! Cheers!